# htaccess not redirecting because of '?'

Tags: .htaccess

I'm having a problem with my htaccess, we've moved a website and they're old website had a lot of duplicate pages that had a `?cat_id=88` etc... on them, I'm trying to redirect the page but it's not working, I've put the redirect code below, I'm already redirection the `mantra.html` to the `/Mantra` but the version with the `?cat_id=79` isn't redirecting, it's just ignoring everything after the `?`

```
Redirect 301 /mantra.html?cat_id=79 http://www.website.co.uk/Mantra
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect only accepts paths, not paths with querystring. You could use mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat_id=79$
RewriteRule ^mantra\.html$ /Mantra? [R=302,L]
```

change 302 to 301 once you get it working (301 are aggressively cached by browsers and make debugging a nightmare).

**EDIT** added a `?` at the end to remove any querystring. Apache removes the `?` if there is no other data in the querystring, so the end user will never see it.

Comment: And don't forget a `?` at the end of the target if you want to strip the existing query string.

Comment: Good suggestion Ignacio. Added it to the post.